# Is there a more efficient way to disable multiple scripts while keeping some active on a single game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to turn off all components instead of one of them on a Game Object based off of which number is chosen as the index. The code is longer than this but I am trying to figure out if there is a more efficient way to doing so rather than calling so many GetComponents. When running this code I am getting a StackOverflowException and I think it is because of how many time I am calling GetComponent. The idea that I had was to put each GetComponent into an array and if the index matches the array number than make that component true and make the rest false. I that is the right direction can some help me in the right direction on how I create arrays out of scripts.

```
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV1>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV2>().enabled = false;
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV3>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV4>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Negative>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Lightning>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_MetalFX>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Pixel8bitsC64>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_GoldFX>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Waterfall>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Hologram>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_PlasmaRainbow>().enabled = false; 

        break;

    case 1:
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV1>().enabled = true; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV2>().enabled = false;
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV3>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV4>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Negative>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Lightning>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_MetalFX>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Pixel8bitsC64>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_GoldFX>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Waterfall>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Hologram>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_PlasmaRainbow>().enabled = false;  

        break;
    case 2:
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV1>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV2>().enabled = true;
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV3>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV4>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Negative>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Lightning>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_MetalFX>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Pixel8bitsC64>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_GoldFX>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Waterfall>().enabled = false;
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Hologram>().enabled = false; 
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_PlasmaRainbow>().enabled = false; 

        break;
    }
```

Comment: You could turn it into a method which accepts an `integer` with a list of the components like you have in your select and just use the integer as an index to know which Component to turn on (set to true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `GetComponent<>` is quite costly. Don't do it in `Update` if you can avoid it.

Avoiding means: if these components stay the whole time, you can cache the references:

```
private List<GameObject>() all_components = new List<GameObject>();
```

And then, you may add them in `Start()`, and call GetComponent just once per component:

```
void Start()
{
    foreach(Component c in transform.children)
    {
        all_components.Add(c);
    }
    // Or even GetComponentsInChildren, where (true) includes the inactive gameobjects!
}
```

[GetComponentsInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

Alternatively, only the ones you want:

```
all_components.Add(GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV1>());
all_components.Add(GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV2>());
// and so on... (but in Start - so just once per runtime :))
```

If you want maximum performance, e.g. even avoid this spike at start, do this:

```
public Gameobject[] all_components_array;
```

And in Inspector, drag them all in. You may need to specify the array size first. However, no need to collect them in `Start()` anymore :)

Now, how to disable/enable?

This disables all:

```
for(int i = 0; i < all_components.Count; i++)
{
    all_components[i].SetActive(false);
}
```

If you want to disable "all but 2" - disable all, then enable the 2 you want:

```
all_components[4].SetActive(true);
all_components[9].SetActive(true);
```

You could also activate all, then disable some. Depends on what you want in your switch-case you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps disable all components, then just enable the one you want based on the switch statement?

```
foreach (var c in player.GetComponents<Component>())
{
    if (c is DontDisable1 ||
            c is DontDisable2)
        continue;
    c.enabled = false;
}

switch (index)
{
    case 1:
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV1>().enabled = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV2>().enabled = true;
        break;
}
```

Comment: There are some scripts that I never want to disable though.

Comment: @DarkT Exclude them in the foreach loop.

Comment: code-wise - it's easier than OPs way. Similar to my suggestions. Performance-wise - it's better not to use `GetComponents<>`. Impact depends on how often this is called.

Comment: Indeed.  I wasn't aiming for performance.  Caching in Start, then using works better.